# reuse a calculated field in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-field

I have this query.

```
SELECT carte.nome, sum(amount) AS total, (1500-sum(amount)) AS residuo 
FROM movimenti_carta JOIN carte ON movimenti_carta.banca=carte.id 
WHERE data BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31' 
GROUP by banca
```

The goal of this query is to sum some amounts (sum(amount)) in a period of time. I also set a floor to this amount at 1500 so I want to do the math in the third field. I tried to do

```
SELECT carte.nome, sum(amount) AS total, (1500-total) AS residuo 
FROM movimenti_carta JOIN carte ON movimenti_carta.banca=carte.id 
WHERE data BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31' 
GROUP by banca
```

but mysql complains that totale is not a known field (it is a derived one). 
The first query works but it is not efficient. What am I missing for the second one to work?

Comment: what  do you mean with  " it is not efficient. " ..  ???   the use of two  or more time for the same aggregation function (based on same gruo by)  don't reduce the performance

Comment: @scaisEdge i didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column aliases cannot be re-used in the `SELECT` where they are defined -- and for a simple reason.  MySQL (in particular) and SQL in general does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `SELECT`.

In your case, the simplest solution is to repeat the expression, because it is so simple.

You have another problem in your query, though.  You are aggregating by `banca` but only selecting `nome`.

Here is a better way to write the query:

```
SELECT c.nome, sum(?.amount) AS total,
       (1500 - sum(?.amount)) AS residuo 
FROM movimenti_carta mc JOIN
     carte c
     ON mc.banca = c.id 
WHERE ?.data >= '2019-05-01' AND
      ?.data < '2019-06-01' 
GROUP by c.nome;
```

Note the changes:

- All column references should be qualified.  The `?` is for the alias for the table where the column comes from.
- Use table aliases, which are abbreviations of the table names.
- The unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` are in the `GROUP BY`.
- The date arithmetic works for both dates and date/time values.

Comment: "SQL in general does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the SELECT." - but **if** the SQL standard did define it, then we _could_ reuse column expressions in same-level `SELECT`  clauses and avoid the (current) excessive level of repetitiveness and verbosity in queries like that - so why don't they? It would be an immediate and huge ergonomics boost for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Common Table Expression (CTE):

```
WITH cte_query AS (
SELECT carte.nome AS nome, sum(amount) AS total
FROM movimenti_carta JOIN carte ON movimenti_carta.banca=carte.id 
WHERE data BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31' 
GROUP by banca
)

SELECT nome, total, (1500- total) AS residuo 
FROM cte_query
```

Subquery would also work:

```
SELECT nome, total, (1500- total) AS residuo 
FROM (
SELECT carte.nome AS nome, sum(amount) AS total
FROM movimenti_carta JOIN carte ON movimenti_carta.banca=carte.id 
WHERE data BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31' 
GROUP by banca
) A
```

Comment: I prefer to do it in a single query. But thanks for the CTE hint

Answer (score 0):

Mysql doesnt support using variables unless it is inside of HAVING statement, so for this to work you should rewrite it as

```
SELECT carte.nome, sum(amount) AS total, (1500-sum(amount)) AS residuo 
FROM movimenti_carta JOIN carte ON movimenti_carta.banca=carte.id 
WHERE data BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31' 
GROUP by banca
```

Comment: That is what I am currently doing

Comment: so yes, its basically the only way to do it, it sounds not efficient in programming meaning but its the way how to do it in mysql, and it, wouldnt recalculate it actually twice as it has some internal variable storage, but you just cant use them.

Comment: Oh yea so you do :( My Mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can right it as

```
SELECT 
nome ,
total,
 residuo AS residuo_TMP,
 (1500-total) AS residuo 
 FROM 
 (SELECT 
carte.nome,
SUM(amount) AS total,
(1500- SUM(amount)) AS residuo 
 FROM
movimenti_carta 
JOIN carte 
  ON movimenti_carta.banca = carte.id 
 WHERE DATA BETWEEN '2019-05-01' 
AND '2019-05-31' 
GROUP BY banca ) aa
```

Comment: My first query is working and is a simpler approach compared to a subquery

Comment: oooh nice keep it up //